# Neovim color scheme theme installation fails

Tags: macos, vim, colors, neovim

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'two-firewatch'
call plug#end()
set background=dark
let g:two_firewatch_italics=1
colo two-firewatch
```

Above is the entire contents of init.vim

I'm not sure what should be placed in the plugged, autoload, and colors folders under .config/nvim

If I am to use Plug, what is the name of the theme? I don't think it's mentioned on the webpage. Above I've written two-firewatch.

https://github.com/rakr/vim-two-firewatch

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tel with what I can see, there is a problems in your config. I'm guessing you're using vim-plug as a plugin manager.

You should have something like this:

```
call plug#begin()

Plug 'ayu-theme/ayu-vim'

call plug#end() " <<<< Do not forget to call plug#end

set termguicolors
let ayucolor="light"
colorscheme ayu
```

If that's your whole config then it should work fine assuming you call `:PlugInstall` to install `ayu-vim`.

Comment: Thanks so much, is it supposed to look like that?

Comment: I have never used this color scheme so I don't know what could be the cause of your problem. I have tried it on my computer with the config I gave you and it looks fine. At least like the screenshots on the github repo. Make shure that you don't have other lines which could interfere with the theme. Maybe the problem comes from the version of Neovim you're using (I have version 0.4.4). Check the github issues of the project if you feel like the problem comes from the plugin.

Comment: Can I see a photo of what yours looks like. I am confused about the contents of two files. The vimrc file under ~/ and the init.vim file in located under nvim which is beneath .config

Comment: The `~/.vimrc` file is read by vim **not** by neovim and `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` is read by neovim **not** by vim. If you put the code I gave you in `init.vim`, neovim should be able to install the plugin and use it. If you put it in `.vimrc` it should also work for vim. Some plugins may have issues with vim but it should work with neovim as it did for me. If the bug persist, try another theme and/or try to clean the files in `~/.config/nvim/plugged`. I could send a screenshot but it just looks like the github page. I can't help you much more than that.

Comment: I'm trying two-firewatch but I can't get it to install using Plug. https://github.com/rakr/vim-two-firewatch. The error is Invalid argument: two-firewatch (implicit `vim-scripts' expansion is deprecated)